# Prevent touchmove from triggering mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to detect mousedrag event and not have it fired by a touchmove event.

I current have a "mousemove(function(e){})" function but it is being fired by touchmove as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
$('#your_id').on('touchmove',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

});
```